# How do I get rid of the div that wraps every input in a simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

This input:

```
<%= f.input :keywords, label: false, :input_html => {:class => "span8"}, :placeholder => "Park Slope, Prospect Heights, Fort Green..." %>
```

Produces this:

```
<div class="control-group string optional">
  <div class="controls">
     <input class="string optional span8" id="search_keywords" name="search[keywords]" placeholder="Park Slope, Prospect Heights, Fort Green..." size="50" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I just generate the `input` alone without the divs around it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So it seems the best way to do this is to use `f.input_field`.

The docs for Simple_Form don't quite spell it out, but you can view the actual [API docs here](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:input_field).

From the docs:

```
simple_form_for @user do |f|
  f.input_field :name
end
```

Will Produce:

```
<input class="string required" id="user_name" maxlength="100"
   name="user[name]" size="100" type="text" value="Carlos" />
```

Answer (score 22):

Well do something like this pass a params `wrapper: false` like this

```
<%= f.input :keywords, 
            label: false,
            wrapper: false,
            input_html: { class: 'span8' }, 
            placeholder: 'Park Slope, Prospect Heights, Fort Green...' %>
```

And See it would work

Hope this help

Comment: Almost there. It gets rid of one of the wrapper divs. i.e. from the question, it got rid of the div with `class="control-group string optional"`. It didn't get rid of the `div class=controls`. So the layout is still broken. Thoughts?

Comment: The only wrapper code is in the question. You can see the two divs around the `input`. One with class of `control-group string optional` and another with class of `controls`. Also, the `f.input...` simple_form helper produces that output. Did you want to see something other than that?

Comment: Oh...it's a very popular gem - where you can see the source here - https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/

Comment: @marcamillion Sorry man I did not ask for the gem source I asked for the file that simple_form gem generated for u using it generated inside your initializer folder I mean `config/intializer/simple_form.rb`

Answer (score 1):

use the regular `text_field`

```
<%= f.text_field :keywords, :class => "string optional span8", :placeholder => "Park Slope, Prospect Heights, Fort Green..." %>
```

Comment: You are on a TEAR this evening aren't you homey. Great idea! The thing is though...I will still want to use the `simple_form_for` fields for some other elements in my form. Is there no way to disable those wrapper divs?