# How do I generate this select tag in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to generate this:

```
<select class="input-small">
   <option value="1">1+ bd</option>
   <option value="2">2+ bd</option>
   <option value="3">3+ bd</option>
   <option value ="4">4+ bd</option>
   <option value ="5">PH</option>
</select>
```

I tried this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :num_bedrooms, ["1+ br", "2+ br", "3+ br", "4+ br", "PH"], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], {}, {:class => "input-small"} %>
```

But that gives me this:

```
TypeError at /    
Message {} is not a symbol
```

How do I generate that select tag with the collection select?

Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

This is the output produced @shrimpsushi's answer:

```
<select id="search_num_bedrooms" name="search[num_bedrooms]"><option value="<option value="1">1+ bd</option>
<option value="2">2+ bd</option>
<option value="3">3+ bd</option>
<option value="4">4+ bd</option>">collection</option>
<option value="input_html" class="input-small">input_html</option></select>
```

Notice the weird `"> collection</option>` tag after the 4th option. Not to mention the `input_html` option value that has the class applied to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :num_bedrooms, options_for_select({"1+ br" => 1, "2+ br" => 2}), {}, class: 'input-small' %>
```

Comment: The class doesn't apply, for some strange reason. I even tried the hashrocket version.

Comment: I have updated the question with the output that this suggestion produces - which is kinda weird.

Comment: Now everything should be fine. You can also use previous [[],[],[]] options collection if you'd like.

Comment: I'd also recommend checking simple_form gem for further usage. Stands for its name.

Comment: Perfect...this finally works. I actually did start off the using simple_form gem. The issue is that with every `f.input` it wraps each field in 2 divs. I can't figure out how to make it not do that, i.e. just give me the `select` tag or the `input` field without putting them in the 2 divs. Do you know how to do that? It breaks my layout with those excess tags around it- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784668/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-div-that-wraps-every-input-in-a-simple-form